# flutter: not navigating to another page

Tags: flutter, if-statement

what i am trying to get is when i type Id and password in the form i should be able to get into another page. But when i press submit , nothing is happening.The error i am getting is Equality operator `==` invocation with references of unrelated types. Is there any way to solve that?

```
  Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    
                        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                      TextFormField(
                        controller: nameController,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Id'),
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value.isEmpty) {
                            return 'Enter id';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                      ),
                      TextFormField(
                        controller: passwordController,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
                        obscureText: true,
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value.isEmpty) {
                            return 'invalid password';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 30),
                      RaisedButton(
                        child: Text('Submit'),
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (nameController ==  //i am getting a blue underline over here
                                  FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                      .collection("proddecAdmin")
                                      .doc("1")
                                      .set({'Id': ''}) &&
                              passwordController == //i am getting a blue underline over here
                                  FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                      .collection("proddecAdmin")
                                      .doc("1")
                                      .set({
                                    'password': '',
                                  })) {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => ProfilePage()),
                            );
                          }
                        },
```

Answer (score 0):

nameController & password controller are just the `TextEditingController` instances. You want to compare against the value stored in the controllers. e.g.

`nameController.value.text == ''`

`passwordController.value.text == ''`